# How can I make middleware in Express that will return 413 if the request is too large?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What I have here does not seem to return anything to the response. The odd part is that the debug logger shows `POST /ServiceName 413 2ms`

```
var maxSize = 1000*1000;

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  var size = req.headers['content-length'];
  if(size>maxSize){
    var errorMessage = "Request of size "+size+" rejected";
    res.status(413);
    res.send({error:"Please do not send that it makes my server sad"});
    console.error(errorMessage);
  }
  else{
    next();
  }
}
```

Here is the mocha test that dies if that helps anyone.

```
  it('should 413 when the request is over a meg', function(done){
    var x = "1234567890";
    var iterations = 14;
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      x += x+x;
    }
    superagent.post('http://localhost:3000/CartItemAdd')
      .send({ 
        name: x,
        item: '12354'
      })
      .end(function(e,res){
        expect(e).to.eql(null);
        expect(res.status).to.eql(413);
        expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
        done(e)
      })    
  });
```

Comment: My actual problem was trying to respond before using the body parsing middleware. The answer marked below is a good and detailed answer to the main question I was posing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

express.limit middleware will send a 413 for you:

```
app.use(connect.limit('1mb'));
```

You can learn from source code here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/limit.html

If you want to use a middleware for limit body, express.limit is deprecated, you can switch to `raw-body`:

`$npm install raw-body`

```
var getRawBody = require('raw-body')

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  getRawBody(req, {
    length: req.headers['content-length'],
    limit: '1mb',
    encoding: 'utf8'
  }, function (err, string) {
    if (err)
      return next(err)

    req.text = string
    next()
  })
})
```

Readme: https://github.com/stream-utils/raw-body

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may just simply be how you're getting the Content-Length header out.

The `request` has a [`get` method](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.get) for case-insensitively pulling out headers.

I'm guessing `req.get('content-length')` or `req.headers['Content-Length']` might do the trick.

Additionally, `size > maxSize` will probably be comparing a string to a number, unless express converts the Content-Length header to a number somewhere. It shouldn't matter, because type coercion will jump into effect here, but worth being aware of.

Comment: The max size is pulling correctly but you are right I should keep an eye on that.